# How to add items with image into NSMenu?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I want to implement similar to this NSMenu into my app which I have shown into the screenshot. I want to add an item with an image like this. Also, I want to assign a title to the group of NSMenuItems.

How can I set an image(icon of the file) to an item of NSMenu? And how can I set the title for the group of NSMenuItems?

**The code I have tried is as below:**

```
NSMenu *statusMenu;

NSMenuItem *itm=[[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:[foldermenuarray objectAtIndex:j] action:@selector(cleanNowPressed:) keyEquivalent:@""];
[itm setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"whiteMenu.png"]];
[statusMenu addItem:itm];
```

I have shown arrows for showing things which are required for my app.

The exact view that I want to achieve is shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does `[NSImage imageNamed:@"whiteMenu.png"]` return an image?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is using xib editor. Select a Menu item from xib->Select 4th tab called "Show the attributes inspector"->Enter you image name->Done!

NOTE: Make sure your custom image is perfect size for your menu item.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to add item programmatically. Image and Title of NSMenuItems will be dynamic.